# How to replace the Nth column in a string separated by '|' in pl/sql

Tags: string, replace, plsql, delimiter

This is my string :

```
strRecord := 'aaa|bbb|123|678|hi|NULL|987|NULL|NULL|aaa|ccc';
```

here delimiter is `|`

I want to change the 6th column (NULL) with some variable in PL/SQL.

How can I do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably easiest with regular expression:

```
strRecord := regexp_replace(strRecord,'\|\w+', '|MEH',1 ,5);
```

To replace the sixth element with the string `'MEH'` set the occurrence as `5`. Note that your delimiter is a pipe, which is the OR operator in regex so you'll need to escape it.

Comment: will it append the 'MEH' with the previous value in the field?

Comment: It replace the string but in the wrong place. i tried 13th field but it chances 31st field I tried this command strRecord := regexp_replace(strRecord,'\,\w+', ','||C.PHONE_NUMBER_INPUT_ID||'BCS',1 ,12); here comma is the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried below statement it appended succesfully to 13th field.    strRecord := regexp_replace(strRecord,'\,\', 'BCS,',1 ,13);